# Lightbox: On my page the first image loads the following ones don't

Tags: image, loading, lightbox2

[page being worked on](http://www.josiahrussellwebdesign.com/fbc/Teens.htm)

Hello all I hope this will be a simple fix I just don't know what is holding up the program.

So here is the scenario, I have just installed lightbox I test just the first image and in worked great no problem. So then I proceeded to group all the images on the page and none of them would open. You will see on the page now I just have two pictures the rest are commented out.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I am seeing, your second image is not appearing because the file you are pointing to has not been uploaded to the site.

For your first image, the "A" tag is referencing 1small.jpg, which is the same as the image.
For your second image, the "A" tag is referencing 125large.jpg, which is different from the image (125small.jpg).

Either upload the missing image, or correct the "A" tag.